# Add newrow from gridview to another gridview

Tags: devexpress

On Form2.GridView1 i click repository button.the selected row will be transmitted at Form1.GridView1.
This code work very well but still i can send a single row. I want if I click the first row in Form2.GridView1 will be transmitted at Form1.GridView1 .. and if as an example I choose a second row I will have in Form1.gridview1 2 rows and so on.
My code :

```
    Private Sub RepositoryItemButtonEdit1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemButtonEdit1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim Dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3"))
    Dr("Column1") = GridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Id")
    Dr("Column2") = GridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Name")
    Dr("Column3") = GridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Surname")
    dt.Rows.Add(Dr)
    Form1.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: And what happens when you execute this code? You need to provide more information as to where you are running into trouble.

Comment: Additionally, if both GridControls are bound to a DataTable, you can use the GridView's [GetFocusedDataRow method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedDataRow.method) to retrieve an instance of the current DataRow. You can use the DataTable.Import row method in form 1 to add this into that grid.

Comment: Thank you very much Brendon .. very nice of you ..  I have a Form2.GirdView1 filled by Items ( RepositoryItemButtonEdit1 - ITEMS_Code - ITEMS_Barcode - ITEMS_Name ) ..

In Form1 i have GridView1 with Columns ( ITEMS_Code - ITEMS_Barcode - ITEMS_Name )
How to make when i click on RepositoryButton in Form 2 .. selected data will be transferred to Form1.GirdView1 ..

Comment: Again, if both GridControl are bound to a DataTable with the same schema (and it seems they are), get the DataRow from GridView 2 using the GetFocusedDataRow in the RepositoryItemButtonEdit's ButtonClick event handler. Pass this DataRow to Form 1 and import it into the DataTable used as the data source for Grid Control 1

Comment: GridControl in Form2 is filled by this code :    Dim InfoCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT itemcode,itembarcode,itemname From tableitems", con)
        Dim InfoAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
        Dim InfoTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
        InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
      GridControl1.DataSource = InfoTable .... but in Form1 .. GridControl1 is empty ( Invoice ) .. i choose items in Form2 and i add choosed items at Form1

Comment: It's fine if the Form 1 grid control is empty as long as it still has a data source set. You can cast the GridControl.DataSource property to a DataTable and use the ImportRow method to insert the DataRow from Form 2 into it.

Comment: I'm really new to this area .. please how to use methode  ( ImportRow to insert the Form 2 DataRow )

Comment: Assuming you have a DataRow "dr" from Form 2, on Form 1 you can simply say: (gridControl1.DataSource as DataTable).ImportRow(dr);

Comment: Thank you for help .. i tried to make it